# Choosing metal plate to spread point load

Tags: stresses, metals, strength

I have a heavy object standing on 4 legs (about 30 mm in diameter each) on a wooden floor. The object is soon going to become even more heavier and I am concerned the legs could penetrate the floor. As a precautionary measure I am about to put a metal plate under the legs to spread the load:

[image]

Would a steel plate of the same thickness spread the load significantly better than an aluminium one? Which property of the metal is the plate's load-spreading performance a function of — strength (tensile, shear), hardness? Is this function linear? Would a twice-as-thick aluminium plate perform not worse than a steel plate?

Comment: What is the joist below the floor, their spacing? I would strengthen from below, or use a thick wood board rather than a steel plate.

Comment: @r13 The floor is actually a typical shipping container floor: thick plywood on steel ribs half-a-meter apart or so. So it is not changing.

Comment: Steel is three times the density of aluminum and about three times everything else too, strength and stiffness modulus included. But stiffness of an actual object scales to the cube of the thickness. So an aluminum plate of the same weight as steel will be 3x thicker and quite a 9 times stiffer. An aluminum plate twice the thickness of a steel plate will be 2.6x stiffer.

Comment: @DKNguyen Sounds like an acceptable answer!

Comment: If this is a shipping container, you shall match it with the same type of metal, otherwise, need to watch out for galvanic action/effect.

Comment: @r13 Good point. I will just put PVC under the plate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steel is three times the density of aluminum and about three times everything else too, strength and stiffness modulus included. But stiffness of an actual object scales to the cube of the thickness. So an aluminum plate of the same weight as steel will be 3x thicker but a 9 times stiffer than a steel plate. An aluminum plate twice the thickness of a steel plate will be 2.6x stiffer.

Comment: 2.6x is 8/3 to be precise if the strength/stiffness modulus is 3 times different.